# Infinity Time value in java?

Tags: java, time

is there any possible to get the infinty time value in milliseconds? that is i set that time delay value must be shows the window when the user close the application? any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but I'll try to answer it anyway.

Milliseconds are usually represented using values of type `long`. There is no way to let a `long` value represent infinity. However, the `Long.MAX_VALUE` equals 9223372036854775807, which, if interpreted as milliseconds, corresponds to **292471208 yeas**. Perhaps that's long enough for you? :-)

Comment: What, you don't believe in infinite uptime? Shame on you! :-).  Plus  you must subtract 40 years, that has passed already from 1970. This makes it so less infinity.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but isn't Long.MAX_VALUE good enough? It is equivalent to 292471208 years...